# Jersey+Spring integration and web.xml

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I'm trying to make jersey+spring integration.

I have question about web.xml configuraiton.

This example includes SpringServlet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>
                             com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages
                    </param-name>
        <param-value>com.mkyong.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/

But another example doesn't include SpringServlet.

https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.25/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

The last example includes:

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.examples.helloworld.spring.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

and in MyApplication class it extends ResourceConfig and register RequestContextFilter.class.

My questions are.

1-)What is the main difference between two web.xml configuration?

2-)Why the second example extends ResourceConfig and register RequestContextFilter.class ?

Answer (score 0):

A jersey ServletContainer(SpringServlet in this case) can be initialized in multiple ways..

The first example just registers the package to look for the required resource since it's a simplified example.

However in cases where you need to define multiple configurations, that can be done using an init parameter with the name [ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.21/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer.html) that refers to a class implementing [Application](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/2.0/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html).

This Application instance(org.glassfish.jersey.examples.helloworld.spring.MyApplication) can define all servlet level configurations like mappers,filters etc.